# How do I define limits for my inputs in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, limit

I'm trying to define limits for my inputs in python:

```
hp_cur=int(input("Enter the current number of HP (1-75): "))
hp_max= int(input("Enter the maximum number of HP (1-75): "))
hp_dif=(hp_max-hp_cur)
```

I would like to limit the input of hp-cur to 1-75 and both limit the hp-max input and make sure the input is larger than the hp-cur input.

Comment: If the input is out of range, do you want to ask the user to enter the number again,  or should the code automatically adjust the number so it is in range?

Comment: did you came to a solution with the suggested answers? then please accept/vote up :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can check the input and if it is not inside the limit, you can ask the user to input again.

You would realize this with a `while` loop.

```
while True:    
    try:
        hp_cur=int(input("Enter the current number of HP (1-75): "))
    except ValueError: # used to check whether the input is an int
        print("please insert a int type number!")
    else: # is accessed if the input is a int
        if hp_cur < 1 or hp_cur > 75:
            print("please insert a number in the given limit")
        else: # if number is in limit, break the loop
            break
```

you can do the same for your second desired input, and compare them afterwards. if it is a negative number, you can ask the user to input the numbers again by putting both "validity checks" inside a bigger `while`-loop, which you `break` when the returned number is positive.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    answer = input('Enter the current number of HP (1-75): ')

    try:
        # try to convert the answer to an integer
        hp_cur = int(answer)

    except ValueError:
        # if the input was not a number, print an error message and loop again
        print ('Please enter a number.')
        continue

    # if the number is in the correct range, stop looping
    if 1 <= hp_cur <= 75:
        break

    # otherwise print an error message, and we will loop around again
    print ('Please enter a number in the range 1 to 75.')
```